# How to enable vtk "direct" hardware rendering, X11 / Ubuntu 11.04 x86-64?

Tags: linux, opengl, cmake, vtk

I notice that the `IsDirect()` method which should say whether hardware rendering is on returns false on my vtkRenderWindow*, link to class doc:
http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderWindow.html

How do I enable it? Seems like a build option in cmake should do it, but what? My OpenGL libs are found OK. I notice there's a thread from a while back here: http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2005-July/081034.html   but I don't see any more recent info so far, is it just not supported on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I doubt it is a cmake option to enable direct HW rendering.

Applications are falling back to the software rending when the hardware rendering is not possible (GPU doesn't support some of the picked options).

Without seeing some code and getting details (which GPU), it is not possible to give a better answer.